# Remove default markers in google maps

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-markers

I recently learn t to add custom markers to the Google maps. So i created a route with directions API. After that I added my own markers. Now i am facing a problem where both, the original one and the custom one are showing up. How can i remove the default markers to show my originals one.

[image]

Code I wrote to add custom markers

```
 function addmarkers()
   {
             $.each(order,function(key,value)
                     {
                       geocoder.geocode( { 'address': waypts[value]}, function(results) 
                       {
                                var source = 'images/markers/'+i+'.png';
                                var latlang =  results[0].geometry.location;
                                var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                                position: latlang,
                                map: map,
                                icon: source
                               });     
                       });                               
                    });


   };
```

I am calling this function just after the `initialize()` function

```
           function initialize()                  // creating maps
                { 
                    google.maps.visualRefresh = true;
                    currentlocation = new google.maps.LatLng(mylat,mylong);
                    var mapoptions = 
                    {
                      zoom: 14,
                      mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP,
                      center: currentlocation
                    }
             map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'),mapoptions);
                        addmarkers();
                        directionsDisplay.setMap(map);
```

};

Now you can see in the pic, I am getting both the default as well as the customized markers. Where is this going wrong ?

Comment: I cant get your issue...u have to just add the custom markers not the default ones...u might be repeating..please provide some code sample..
anyway store markers in an array say markersArray and then `markersArray[index].setMap(null)`

Comment: I have added the code. Look at the picture, this is what i am getting.